# Android Cursor size

Tags: android

Anyone knows how to change cursor size in Edittext in Android???

I'm trying to implement SMS function. 
I used EditText and tried to put background image. 
The background image has lines so I need to put extra space between lines so that the background image and the lines fit nicely.
But... if I use linespacingextra, it increase cursor as well. That means the fontsize will be smaller than the cursor size.

Any idea??